# Making page resize with browser

Tags: html, css

I'm doing the first project for The Odin Project, which is recreating the Google home page. I think mine looks pretty good considering I've only been at this for a few weeks, but when I take my page out of fullscreen mode, a scrollbar appears. If you look at the Google homepage, The page itself resizes instead of using a scrollbar. `Overflow:hidden` obviously will just cut off the bottom of the page, so I don't want that. I'm sorry if I'm not being specific enough, but here's a [link](https://github.com/KevinAllen4325/google-homepage) to my Github to check it out.

And if you see anything that I'm doing completely wrong or messy, I'd really love some criticism.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a look at your GitHub, but I would suggest incorporating [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), which basically lets you develop pages responsive to the screen size.

You might find this tutorial helpful:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look through your Github, you are setting a `min-width: 500px` to your `all` class which contans all your content. Try setting your `all` class `width: 100%` instead. This will allow your content to fill the page and adjust as the screen size adjusts.

Granted, once you get really small and content hits each-other they will break to other lines, but you would have to handle that with a media-query to adjust the size/scaling etc...

```
.all {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all I had to do was remove all your `.all` styles to fix this issue. I also fixed your footer so it sticks to the bottom of the page. Finally, if you want to make the input size well, use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) like so:

```
@media (max-width: 500px /* or whatever */) {
   input {
      width: 80%;
   }
}
```

This will set the input's width to 80% at screen sizes `500px` and smaller. Hre's a pen of what I changed: https://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/pen/pemaoK?editors=0100